# The content of 'position' property need to be consecutive?

Tags: html, seo, schema.org, breadcrumbs, microdata

I have a structured breadcrumb like below:

```html
<ol itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
<li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/">
        <span itemprop="name">Home</span>
    </a>
    <span itemprop="position" content="1">&gt;</span>
</li>

<li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/furniture/">
        <span itemprop="name">Furniture</span>
    </a>
    <span itemprop="position" content="2">&gt;</span>
</li>

<li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
     <a itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/arts/furniture/kitchen/">
         <span itemprop="name">Kitchen</span>
     </a>
     <span itemprop="position" content="3"></span>
</li>
</ol>
```

At the end of each  `li` item I have `itemprop` `position` with the `content` 1, 2, 3. These value must be consecutive or just need to be increased? Like 3, 5, 7.

Comment: The spec does not clarify. Parsers of structured data would probably be lenient and not have issues with it. The best thing is to test it with what system you want to use it. e.g. check if Google shows the breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 0):

I threw it into the bottom of my page on the SDTT to see what would happen. As you've provided an ordered list, 'OL', the numbers should be in ascending order, as you did. The SDTT doesn't really seem to care about the incremental values. If the specific position value represents something more meaningful in a system you're implementing, then don't worry about perfect sequencing. (I like being systematic). If you only have a very small number of items, keep it simple and clean and don't tempt fate.